# SQL syntax for calculating sum based on two columns and different rows

Tags: sql-server

How to get a field value calculated on other column and current column's previous row.

Expected result as below:

```
Row No, Year, Week, Count, Sum
1,      2015,    1,    10, 10
2,      2015,    2,     5, 15
3,      2015,    3,     3, 18
4,      2015,    4,     1, 19
.          .     .      .  .
.          .     .      .  .
.          .     .      .  .
52,     2015,   52,     n, n
```

Columns [Row No], [Year], [Week] and [Count] are static, I want to calculate the [Sum] as in below equation

```
SUM(Row 1) = Count(Row1)
SUM(Row 2) = Count(Row2) + SUM(Row 1)
SUM(Row 3) = Count(Row3) + SUM(Row 2)
SUM(Row 52) = Count(Row52-1) + SUM(Row52-1)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in sqlserver 2012 you can use [running sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
SELECT 
  SUM([Count]) over (order by year, week) [Sum]
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: @DeepanshuKalra the performance in that example is really bad, It will cause (N-1)/2 * N joins. I would use a subselect for better performance if i were using 2008.

Comment: You are right ...but this will help in understanding it better if he doesn't know how over clause works.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Super simple solution. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using subquery.

```
Select table.[Row No],Year,Week,Count,Count + IsnUll(t1.Count,0)
from Table
LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select Count,[Row No]-1 as [Row No] from Table) ON Table.[Row No]=t1.[Row No]
```

Comment: The solution with Sum Over is the best one and very optimize.